# Use "for" loop inside a new window using "START"

Tags: batch-file, batch-processing

I need to search through a file and get some result but using a new window.

If I run the "for" loop with out the START command am getting the correct results, but when I open the process in a new windows the results are wrong.

```
Start "" /Min Cmd.exe /C For /f "tokens=1,2,3" %%a in (file.txt) do (
set value1=%%a
set value2=%%b
)
echo.  %value1%
echo.  %value2%
```

This is what am getting as a result:

```
%a
%b
```

Comment: I haven't tried it, but you probably want `%a` etc. instead of `%%a`.  Without the `start`, you _would_ need the doubled percent (assuming you're calling this from a `.BAT` file) but when you use `start` _it_ won't be running a batch file, it will be running a direct command, so would only want one percent.  You _may_ also need to lose the parentheses and have everything on one line: something like `,,, do set "value1=%%a" && set "value2=%%b"`

Comment: What you are attempting is not logical. You should explain what your end goal is (why you are attempting to run FOR via START) There very well may be a simple solution, totally different than what you are trying.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I'm not sure what you expect.

**Possibility 1)** - You want the ECHO statements to run in your parent batch script, displaying the result of the FOR /F command that was run in another window.

This simply cannot be done. You cannot execute a FOR command in one window, and process the iterations (the DO portion) in another window.

Also, if you manage to run the entire FOR loop in another window, any variables you set will be totally separate from your parent batch environment. Your parent batch script will not have access to the variables from the other window.

**Possibility 2)** - You want everything (including the ECHO statements) to run within the new Window.

This is possible, but awkward, and can also be problematic depending on the file content.

You must put the entire "script" as a single line that gets passed as a parameter to the CMD /C command. Quoting and escaping can quickly become tricky. The entire line will be parsed in a single pass, so you would need the child window to use delayed expansion. But FOR loops will corrupt content if delayed expansion is enabled and the content includes `!`. You cannot toggle delayed expansion ON and OFF within the loop because the new window has a command line context, not batch, so the SETLOCAL ENABLEDELAYEDEXPANSION command does not work.

I don't see what possible purpose this serves, but the following will run, with the constraint that values containing `!` will be corrupted. I had to add a PAUSE command so that you have an opportunity to see the output.

```
start "" /min cmd.exe /v:on /c "(for /f "tokens=1,2" %%a in (file.txt) do @set "value1=%%a"&set "value2=%%b")&echo(!value1!&echo(!value2!&pause"
```

Comment: Thank you for your answer dbenham,  – If I cannot present the result in the parent batch script then the “START” is not what am looking for.
I will post a new question then. Let me know if you can help. 
Question : Speed up reading results in batch script.

Answer (score 0):

When you use a FOR loop in a bat file you need to double the %%. From the command line (which is your case... since you are starting a new instance of CMD.exe) only use single %. Change both occurrences of %%a to %a and %%b to %b and it will work.

Comment: No, the START command is within a batch script, so the percents need to be doubled. By the time the FOR command is executed in the new window, the double percents will have become a single percent. The problem is totally unrelated to doubling percents.